# Switch button using paper js not work

Tags: paperjs

I'm trying to make a simple image editor using canvas. My code is here `http://jsfiddle.net/qrd3muyh/`.

How to make the switch button to work? If I run it in my localhost, I got these error when clicking the button pencil : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

And when clicking the circle button : `Uncaught ReferenceError: myCircle is not defined`.

Why does it happen and any clue to solve it? Many thanks before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because all `PaperScript` tags become a scoped object (referred to as a `PaperScope`). The reason you are getting the undefined error is because the jQuery callback function has no reference to `myCircle`, etc.

To resolve this, you should access the currently active paper scopes via the `paper` object.

```
$('#pencil').on('click', function(){
    console.log(paper.tools); # See how many tools are in your paper object
    paper.tools[1].activate(); # Activate one of them.
});
$('#circle').on('click', function(){
    paper.tools[0].activate(); # Activate the other.
});
```

To get the currently active tool, you can do this:

```
$('#pencil').on('click', function(){
    var current = paper.tool; # Access currently active tool.
    current.remove();       # remove this tool 
});
```

[Here](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/) is some good reading about the `PaperScopes`.

Comment: Ach, so.. I got it now.. Thanks for the help :)